# How to get value of session variable using jQuery in external js file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC5 project in which i am setting session value in controller using setSession() which is userId.
Then i need to retrieve or get that value in .js file (and set it to TextBox)

but can not get that value in .js file.

following is my .js file code

```
function populateUser() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/UserProfile/SetSessionValues',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    var user = $.session.get("UserName");
                    $("#txtUserName").val(user);  

                                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error :" + msg.responseText);
            },

        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using [AlexChittock / JQuery-Session-Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)? And What are you getting in `data`

Comment: Where are you setting the `userId`? On the client or on the server? If it is at the client, show us the code.

Comment: @Satpal i am not using any plugin you mentioned. and i am getting return string which controller method returning in data

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman i am setting userId in Controller

Answer (score 2):

In your controller :-

```
ViewBag.myVar = HttpContext.current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

You can assign Parameters as value of control

```
<input type="hidden" value = "@ViewBag.myVar" id="myHiddenVar" />
```

and get it in js file easily

```
alert($('#myHiddenVar').val());
```

Comment: `value"@ViewBag.myVar"` should be `value="@ViewBag.myVar"`

Comment: @Neel just to test i tried this :  Session["UserName"] = "Trupti Rane";
               ViewBag.myVar = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString(); and then access it from cshtml page using <input readonly id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" size="50" style="width: 200px;" value="@ViewBag.myVar"/> but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RazorJS](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files). You can find it in your Nuget Package Manager.

It allows you to use razor like tags (ex: @data) in your `.js` files.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript variables like this:

HTML:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @RenderSection("my_script_variables", false)

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/external.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...

</head>
```

Razor:

```
@Section my_script_variables {

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var variable1 = '@myVar1',
            variable2 = '@Session["myVar2"]',
            variable3 = '@ViewBag.myVar3';

        </script>

}
```

External JS:

```
alert(variable1 + ' ' +variable2 +' '+ variable3);
```

Also, you can use Hidden Variables as suggested by Neel.

Try the solutions at this link:

[Pass Session or Viewbag values to JS Files](http://techbrij.com/pass-session-viewbag-values-js-file-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Although the link might be useful, it is better to include relevant parts of it in your post.

Comment: You can still edit your post to include that information. Otherwise it is likely to get deleted.